# Maven: The scm url does not contain a valid delimiter

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to get automatic buildNumers working but I keep running into the error

The scm url does not contain a valid delimiter

Here's the relevant part of the pom.

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:${source.repo}</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:${source.repo}</developerConnection>
    <url>${source.repo}</url>
</scm>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>        
            <goals>
                <goal>create</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <revisionOnScmFailure>1</revisionOnScmFailure>
        <format>{0,number}</format>
        <items>
            <item>buildNumber0</item>
        </items>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<properties>
    <source.repo>svn://myserver/repository/${project.artifactId}</source.repo>
    [..]
</properties>
```

The subversion location contains two sub projects core and web.

If anyone can help, I feel like I've tried everything.

I've tried the following:

- using pipes: invalid url
- retrieving a list of items from the server using the repo url from the command line: works fine
- adding /trunk to the repo url: delimiter error
- adding /trunk/core to the repo url: delimiter error
- adding /trunk/web to the repo url: delimiter error

The delimiter error is probably hiding a different error because I dont think the url is wrong.

Here's the stack

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The scm url does not contain a valid delimit
    er.
            at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.ScmUrlUtils.getDelimiter(ScmUrlUtils.ja
    va:61)
            at org.apache.maven.scm.manager.AbstractScmManager.makeScmRepository(Abs
    tractScmManager.java:186)
            at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.getScmRepository(CreateMojo.java:7
    68)
            at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.getScmBranch(CreateMojo.java:619)
            at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.execute(CreateMojo.java:464)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPlugi
    nManager.java:490)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(Defa
    ultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLi
    fecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(Defau
    ltLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHan
    dleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegmen
    ts(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLi
    fecycleExecutor.java:180)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:6
    0)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
    java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
    sorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
            at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
            at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)

            at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
```

Thanks,
Marc

Comment: A knee-jerk, gut reaction sort of question... what happens if you copy and paste the url into each scm url instead of trying to use a property to substitute the same in for the 3 urls?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the command:

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

And check the output.  That and the other [help commands](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/usage.html) should help you trouble-shoot your Maven settings (e.g. expression evaluation, profiles, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It is possibly because you are using a placeholder in the URI, and Maven is not expanding it before using it.

I've battled this kind of thing myself with Maven, and sometimes you just have to give up and do the expansion by hand.

---

Another possibility was that the expanded URL `scm:svn:svn://myserver/repository/....` was wrong, but @ach_l's comment convinces me that's not the problem.

Comment: It would be scm:svn:http: if they're running subversion over DAV. But scm:svn:svn: could be correct if they're running over svnserve http://maven.apache.org/scm/subversion.html